# Assets loaded from CSS using url() not using CDN

Tags: webpack, css-loader, webpack-4

I am using a CDN, and have set `__webpack_public_path__` to the CDN URL.

CSS and JS files are loaded by webpack from the CDN.

However, assets loaded from CSS using `url()` are downloaded from the app's domain.

Example:

`app.css` contains:

`.close-button { background-image: url('/images/close-btn-bg.png') }`

`app.css` - downloaded from the CDN

`images/close-btn-bg.png` - downloaded from the app's domain

Can I get webpack to also download `images/close-btn-bg.png` from the CDN?

One very important note is that I do not know the CDN url at buildtime, only at runtime.

Comment: You are using an absolute path for your png (leading `/`). Try using a relative path (removing the leading slash for example).

Comment: did you find an answer to this?